# rails 4 use multiple form builders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on an rails app that uses the rails bootstrap form (github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) gem for the app's forms. Currently there is validations written for the server using Rails model validations and client side validations written in jQuery that get called before the request is made to the server. I saw that there are different gems out there including [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) or [judge](https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge) to DRY up the code by using the model validations on both the client and server, but they themselves are custom form builders.

My question is whether there is a way to use multiple form builders (like bootstrap_form_for and and judge) when creating the view? It'd be convenient if there was a way to "pipe" the form through multiple form builders instead of having to write a custom form builder myself.